# Using a variable as structure identifier

Tags: c, struct, declaration

I've got a small question regarding dynamic structure definitions.
When declaring a structure definition under ANSI-C, is it possible to use a "string"-variable as a structure identifier like below?

```
*(a_string_var) = "username";
struct user *(a_string_var);
```

Comment: What do you expect this to do? The answer is no, anyway, but what's it supposed to mean?

Comment: @hobbs I think the intention would be a `struct user` variable named `username`.

Comment: My intention indeed was to create a structure with a variable identifier. To be more specific to create a username starting with the first letter of the firstname, and the full surname.
I know i can create an array of structs, but in that case the structure identifier would become something like user[0]. but that's something i've been trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

No, all declarations in C must use static, inline identifiers.

Comment: Thanks mate, that's exactly what i wanted to know. :)